# internationalization java web service error messages

Tags: java, internationalization

With Java rest web services,what is the best way to handle internationalization and localization of error messages ?
I do not have jsp pages or any UI. I have web services and I have to return error codes and error messages based on the locale that I get in the request.

I have checked jErr framework and am not able to find any other frameworks which do that. Are there any other options. 
Please help me with the best way to do this.
I checked this post [How to externalize error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597081/how-to-externalize-error-messages) which is very similar to my question but I do not have any client side coding . So i really doubt if I can use resource bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ResourceBundle` this way:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "CA");
ResourceBundle errors = ResourceBundle.getBundle("errors", locale);
System.out.println(errors.getString("user.notFound"));
```

First you create a `Locale` instance (you say you get the locale in the request) and then you pass it to the `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` method along with the name of the resource bundle to load.

Reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundle is not limited to be used in client side code. Its a generic abstraction irrespective of where it is used.

You can have multiple properties files
1. ApplicationMessages.properties
2. ApplicationMessages_fr_FR.properties (for french)

in your error resolver logic you can do

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationMessages",The locale you get from request);
String errorMsg = bundle.getString("502");
```

Use this errorMsg howsoever you like . Set it in response or log etc.